# Notification of posts including your business place on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-notifications

As per title, I'd like to know if there is a way to get proper notifications about posts that include my local business on Facebook, more specifically I'd like to be notified when people tag my page as the place of their posts (the old sign-in IIRC now counted on new pages layouts as visits).

I'm looking for a way to have a notification with a link to those posts so that I can check and "review" what the posters are saying about the business mentioned. This is particularly important specifically when people write posts-like-reviews but on their own timeline, we usually always thanks and welcome reviews on our page, but this way we can't reply to those people.

Is it possible to obtain this with a setting on Facebook? Or maybe some third-party service or program?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way for you to do this in Facebook's settings, but I think that [Trackur](http://www.trackur.com/social-media-monitoring) can help you to find all the user's mentions about your business if those mentions are public.

You can learn more about what Trackur can do for you, here: [Trackur Help](http://help.trackur.com/hc/en-us/articles/202430476-What-Facebook-Content-Does-Trackur-Monitor-).

Comment: Interesting but quite expensive, still valuable indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be invited to [Facebook Mentions app](https://www.facebook.com/facebookmentions/) which includes an API capable of doing this.

Comment: interesting but unfortunately works only for public figures